# NSString from other UIViewController is null

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Could anyone please explain to me why this isn't working? I think it is a real simple problem, but for some reason I am not getting it.

My problem: I have a NSString in my firstViewController with value "Hello!". Now I want to  display this value in my secondViewController but the output is null.

This is my NSLog

```
2013-03-09  foo[95381:c07] value of foo in BITfirstViewcontroller: Hello!
2013-03-09  foo[95381:c07] value of foo in BITsecondViewcontroller: (null)
```

BITAppDelegate.m

```
#import "BITAppDelegate.h"
#import "BITfirstViewController.h"

@implementation BITAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    BITfirstViewController *fvc = [[BITfirstViewController alloc]init];

    // Create navigationController and set InputViewController as root for navController
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:fvc];

    [self.window setRootViewController:navController];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

BITfirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BITfirstViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *foo;

-(IBAction)showSecondView:(id)sender;


@end
```

BITfirstViewController.m

```
#import "BITfirstViewController.h"
#import "BITsecondViewController.h"

@interface BITfirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation BITfirstViewController

@synthesize foo;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        foo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello!"];
        NSLog(@"value of foo in BITfirstViewcontroller: %@",foo);

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(showSecondView:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)showSecondView:(id)sender;
{

    BITsecondViewController *svc = [[BITsecondViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
}

@end
```

BITsecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@class BITfirstViewController;

@interface BITsecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) BITfirstViewController *fvc;

@end
```

BITsecondViewController.m

```
#import "BITsecondViewController.h"
#import "BITfirstViewController.h"

@interface BITsecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation BITsecondViewController

@synthesize fvc;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"value of foo in BITsecondViewcontroller: %@", fvc.foo);

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

@end

Comment: You're adding the second view controller, but you're never setting `fvc` on it, so it's null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in BITfirstViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)showSecondView:(id)sender;
{

    BITsecondViewController *svc = [[BITsecondViewController alloc]init];
    svc.fvc = self;  // you need to set this property as you prepare the svc
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
}
```

EDIT:

Your `fvc` and `svc` are encapsulated, and don't have direct knowledge about each-other except though the use of properties (at least that's the way we try to do things in OOP).  So, you were correct in creating a `@property` in your `svc` that allowed you to have a handle to your `fvc`, but `[[BITsecondViewController alloc]init]` will simply initialize that pointer to `nil`.  Then you need to set that property to point to the intended object, which in this case is the `fvc`.  Since the `svc` is being build from inside an instance of `BITFirstViewController`, the correct handle to pass in is `self`.

Comment: that worked! thanks, but would you care to (briefly) explain.

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew I was missing something. I have been trying to get this working for a few days now. I have tried several approaches, but it wasn't until today that I realized that my UIViewcontroller was the issue. So I created this 'svc' and 'fvc' setup. I just thought that my NSMutableArray wasn't set up properly in my other program., as all entries were gone when coming back to my 'fvc'.